# OneConnect response is coming empty

Tags: android, kotlin, server, connection, responsive

i dont know why Oneconnect response is coming empty i apply key of server there is data but coming empty "[]" this sign come when i debug, hard to understand whats going on. i was making vpn
i m working in kotlin

```
runBlocking {
    launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            Log.d("MyApp", "Coroutine started") // Log that the coroutine has started

            val oneConnect = OneConnect()
            oneConnect.initialize(this@SplashActivity, "2w0QvmDcWoNfZWTmEukdXSF8JAu4zLka2Br7u1iIvr9*****")
            val response = oneConnect.fetch(true)
            Log.d("MyApp", "API Response: $response")
            try {
                Constants.FREE_SERVERS = oneConnect.fetch(true)
                Constants.PREMIUM_SERVERS = oneConnect.fetch(true)
                Log.d("MyApp", "Data fetched successfully") // Log that data was fetched successfully
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Log.e("MyApp", "IOException: " + e.message) // Log any IOException
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e("MyApp", "Exception: " + e.message) // Log any other exceptions
        }
    }
}
```

```
implementation ("com.github.oneconnectapi:OneConnectLib:v1.0.9")
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>

    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">developer.oneconnect.top</domain>
    </domain-config>

</network-security-config>
```